# Swift change text of back button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, back, navigationbar

I have a small problem with changing the text of the back button in my navigation bar.  My App looks like this:

-> `Navigation Controller1` -> `ViewController1` -> `ViewController2` -Show Detail> `TabBarController` -> `NavigationController2` -> `ViewController3` -> `ViewController4`

I changed the text of the back button for my `ViewController2` by adding

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Test"
```

into the `viewDidLoad()` method from `ViewController1`. But I can't change the text of the back button from `ViewController4`

I made some research and found a few solutions but they didn't work for me.

I tried:

In the `App Delegate` - I am getting a crash: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Please file a radar on UIKit if you see this assertion.`

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
//Code       
 UIBarButtonItem.appearance().title = "Test"
//Code 
return true 
}
```

In the pushed `ViewController3` - Nothing is changing

```
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Test"
```

In `NavigationController2` - Nothing is changing

```
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Test"
```

In `NavigationController2` - Nothing is changing

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

In my **Storyboard** changing the text in the `NavigationItem` - Nothing happens

The best solution would be to set it in the `App Delegate`. But I can't because it is crashing...

Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Crashlog:

```
2015-11-12 15:51:56.444 Name[2988:417662] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x22718f8f 0x30dc9c8b 0x22632c2b 0x262e55e7 0x260358b1 0x25f03439 0x262e2c83 0x25e40baf 0x25e406bb 0x2603f153 0x2603f0cb 0x25d9fd27 0x2605b987 0x2603efb7 0x25d9779d 0x25d96dc7 0x25d96ce1 0x25da154b 0x25da0f6b 0x25e2cf1f 0x25e2c917 0x25e2c6dd 0x25e2c19f 0x25e44a75 0x25e446b5 0x25e44649 0x25d97e43 0x257abd29 0x257a755d 0x257a73e5 0x257a6d81 0x257a6b6f 0x257a0849 0x226dedcd 0x226dc48b 0x226dc893 0x22628f31 0x22628d43 0x2a103201 0x25dfa879 0x10b778 0x3137baaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: show us the code in app delegate. Also post the full crash log

Comment: If you could set the back button in view controller 2 by setting the title of view controller 1, why not set the title of view controller 3 to set the title of the back button in view controller 4?

Comment: @MrT The code to change the title of the back button in the AppDelegate looks like this: UIBarButtonItem.appearance().title = "Test" (If I remove it again everything is working fine). I added the crash log to the question.

Comment: @keithbhunter "In the pushed ViewController3 - Nothing is changing" - 
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Test"
(I am adding this code to ViewController3)

Comment: Set the title of the view controller instead of the backBarButtonItem. Like `self.title = "test"` instead of `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Test"`.

Comment: @keithbhunter if I'll do this my back button has the text "test". But the problem is my ViewController3 will have the title "test". (But I don't want this to happen - This is why I actually want to change the text...) But thanks!

Comment: @keithbhunter you were right. It works vadian mentioned here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33676066/4906484) So actually you were right, tanks :) But I'll keep looking for a "cleaner" solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the title of the back bar button of the destination controller displays automatically the title of the navigation item of the source controller, a way is to set the title of the navigation item in the source view controller

- in `viewWillAppear()` or `viewDidAppear()` to the normal title.
- in `prepareForSegue()` to the title the back bar button is supposed to display.

Comment: Thank you, this is working. I'll make some more research and if I don't find any "cleaner" solution I'll user yours. :)

Comment: If you write the normal title in `viewWillAppear()` you'll have the problem that the title changes if the user plays around with swiping back. I prefer to write it in `viewDidAppear()`

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I would do it

Create a new variable for your bar button at the top of the file:

`var leftBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!`

And then set the the attributes of the button

`self.leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Your title", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "leftButtonAction")`

And finally set the new bar button in your nav controller

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton`

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work for me. But thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me: (use this in your pushed ViewController's `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`)

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem()
    backButton.title = "Your text"
    backButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red], for: .normal)
    navigationController?.viewControllers[(navigationController?.viewControllers.count)! - 2].navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you've outlined the segues, it doesn't appear that ViewController3 should have a back button at all. A **Show Detail** segue replaces the child view controller in a `UISplitViewController` or presents the child modally otherwise. There's nowhere to go back to.

Try this inside `viewDidLoad` on ViewController3 (using pre-Swift 2 syntax):

```
if let _ = self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem {
    print("not nil")
} else {
    print("nil")
}
```

When I try that on a sample project, it's nil. I think that's the core problem.

This bit of hackery works:

```
if let navButtons = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.items {
    if navButtons.count > 0 {
        navButtons[0].title = "Test"
    }
}
```

However, that's pretty awful. Manipulating the title of the presenting `ViewController` (per @vadian's advice) is obviously cleaner.

Comment: The problem isn't ViewController3, it is ViewController4. I want to change the back button of ViewController4. (And normally I have to do this in ViewController3 because ViewController3 is pushing ViewController4. I know this is a bit confusing, sorry)